# How to handle "Open this file" in Selenium with webbrowser Edge?

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have to open an Excel file from SharePoint and refresh it. I can sign in without a problem but I can't handle the "Open this file" prompt from Edge. It's not possible to inspect the prompt that I can locate it. Any ideas?

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()) 
driver.get("https://xxx.xlsx")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i0116"]').send_keys("xxx@xxx.com")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="idSIButton9"]').click()
time.sleep(2)

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Open")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(on_element = element)
action.perform()
```

I tried as well EdgeOptions but I couldn't find the right element.

```
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = Edge(options = options)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please inform the version of your Edge browser? When I try to download the file from SharePoint then it shows [this](https://imgur.com/a/kVPQu27) prompt. Did you disable the automatic download? Try to enable it and set the download location. see whether it prompt differently. The above prompt looks like a confirmation alert but generally alert contains only the OK and Cancel buttons. For testing purposes, also try to set the the `"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",` in `add_experimental_option`.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to download the file. I want to open it. I googled it and it's a common problem that it's not possible to suppress it. My question is more how can I press the Open Button? I can't inspect the button, so I don't have HTML code.

Comment: This dialog is shown by the browser and it is not a part of the webpage. So you will not be able to automate it using the Selenium. You need to use some UI automation library that lets you click the open button. You need to use that library along with the Selenium code.